# Unable to read the license file LICENSE.txt - Creating a cocoapod

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am trying to create a cocoapod and I keep getting this error:

```
Unable to read the license file `LICENSE.txt` for the spec 
'WhiteFlowerFactory (0.0.1)'
```

My podspec code:

```
spec.name = "WhiteFlowerFactory"
spec.version = "0.0.1"

spec.license = { :type => "MIT", :file => "LICENSE.txt" }

spec.source_files = "WhiteFlowerFactory/*.{swift}"

spec.platform = :ios
spec.ios.deployment_target = '11.0'

spec.swift_version = "5.0"
```

And here is where it appears in my project directory:

[image]

What I have tried:

- Moving the LICENSE.txt file to the second "WhiteFlowerFactory" subdirectory
- Renamed to LICENSE.md
- Renamed to LICENSE (no extension)

No matter what, I continually receive the same error.

I am also getting a separate error, and I am not sure if this error is related, but I will add it here just in case:

```
[iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (Could not find a `ios` 
simulator (valid values: ). Ensure that Xcode -> Window -> Devices has
at least one `ios` simulator listed or otherwise add one.) during 
validation.
```

I've had both of these errors for several hours. I deleted Xcode 10.2 and 11.0 beta and all simulators and derived data and just freshly reinstalled Xcode 10.3 and its simulators. Still receiving both errors.

Edit: Just updated from cocoapods 1.6.1 -> 1.7.5, second error is solved, still receiving the license error:

```
Validating spec
-> WhiteFlowerFactory (0.0.1)
- WARN  | [iOS] license: Unable to find a license file
- NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Using new build system
- NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Planning build
- NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Constructing build description

[!] The `WhiteFlowerFactory.podspec` specification does not validate.

[!] Unable to read the license file `LICENSE.txt` for the spec `WhiteFlowerFactory (0.0.1)`
```

Comment: run `pod cache clean --all` and run `pod spec lint` again

Answer (score 0):

The `podspec` should include a source field that describes the location of the source. See docs [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#source).  Typically it describes a github repo along with a version based tag that has been pushed to that repo.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, but my LICENSE file had no extension. So I've removed extension in podspec and it works

```
s.license       = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
```